# Python re.search anomaly

Tags: python, search, substring

I have a routine that searches through a directory of files and extracts a customer number from the filename:

```
import os
import re

suffix= '.csv'

# For each file in input folder, extract customer number 
input_list = os.listdir(path_in)
for input_file in input_list:
        fileInput = os.path.join(path_in,input_file)
        customer_ID = re.search('custID_(.+?)'+suffix,fileInput).group(1)
        print(customer_ID)
```

With `suffix='.csv'` and a folder full of csv files:

> avg_hrly_custID_8147611.csv, avg_hrly_custID_8147612.csv, avg_hrly_custID_8147613.csv ...

I get the expected output:

> 8147611,
>   8147612,
>   8147613...

BUT, with `suffix = '.png'` and a folder of .png image files,:

> yearly_average_plot_custID_8147611.png,
>   yearly_average_plot_custID_8147612.png,
>   yearly_average_plot_custID_8147613.png
>   ...

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Why won't it work for image files?

Comment: Though I don't see why it would work one way and not the other (on https://regex101.com/r/zT7rJ7/1 they do behave the same), you probably want to match `\.csv` and `\.png` instead of `.csv` and `.png` just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the `fileInput` string to make sure you're in the right directory?

Comment: Your regex will fail if there is even one file in the directory whose name doesn't match.  Are you sure every file matches the regex?

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn. There are two subfolders in the directory and that was causing the problem. How could I stop it failing - ie just ignore any mismatches?

Comment: The most straightforward way is to assign the result of `re_search` to a variable, e.g., `match`, and then test `if match:`.  When `re_search` finds a match it will return a match instance, which tests as True; when it does not, it will return None, which tests as False.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BrenBarn spotted the cause of the problem. The regex failed because there was a subdirectory in the directory who's name didn't match. I've solved it by introducing  `try....except`

```
import os
import re

suffix= '.png'

# For each file in input folder, extract customer number 
input_list = os.listdir(path_in)
for input_file in input_list:
        fileInput = os.path.join(path_in,input_file)
        try:
           customer_ID = re.search('custID_(.+?)'+suffix,fileInput).group(1)
           print(customer_ID)
        except:
           pass
```

Comment: Bare `except` is a terrible way to handle errors, and it's even worse when the behavior is to ignore it; you're now masking every possible exception, not just the `AttributeError` from the one known exception. Assigning the result of `search` (say, to a variable named `match`) and running only `if match is not None:` is safest, failing that, at least use `except AttributeError:` so you're not silently ignoring stuff like `KeyboardInterrupt`, `SystemExit`, etc.